# andengine vs no framework development

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to learn to create 2D games on android, and I have heard that andengine is one of the best tools for that. I tried using it, but unfortunately there I have encountered numerous issues with andengine having little documentation, and no stable place where I can learn things. So my question is that what would you recommend to a completely newbie developer? Should I try learning andengine, or learn things the hard way? And can you please provide some good links to learn? So far a lot of links I found were quite old and would not work properly all the time.

Thanks to anyone for their help.

Also just to clarify, I am middle skilled in 2D game development (especially in java and C++), so I know the basic structure, my main issue is making things run on an android since I am completely new to android itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With andengine, your best bet is to download, compile and run the [sample games and examples](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/). From reading through and understanding the source code for those, you'll learn how to use it. The examples in particular are effectively documentation, they're very good!

Comment: +1 for Andengine. Makes life so much easier after you learn to work with it. Like Tom said, learn from the examples and there are tons of resources and tutorials online and an excellent forum for your questions

Comment: Thanks so much! Those examples did help immensely. Usually I learn things by reading API first, but I guess in case of andengine that doesn't apply. Someone should organize it though, it was difficult obtaining the jar for it since there seemed to be so many different jars that were alike.

Comment: Beware, there are no .jars anymore, the whole project is now on GitHub and the proper way to use it is to download the source code and link it with your project. All the .jars are obsolete and contain very old versions of AndEngine. https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine